# How can I inspect the environment variables of a running process?

Tags: macos, command-line, unix

Is there some equivalent (CLI or GUI) to Linux's `/proc/$PID/environ` feature?

Comment: Try `ps eww <PID>` in Terminal.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can inspect environmental variables of running process with

```
ps eww <PID>
```

Comment: Is there a way to pretty print this afterwards?

Comment: I'm on macOS 10.14.4 and this doesn't work for me :(

Comment: It works for me on macOS 10.15.1

Comment: Still good in 2023 in freshly updated MacOS 13.5, thank you

Comment: On 13.6.3, both `ps ewww` and `ps Ewww` are no-go (only prints PID, TT, STAT, TIME, COMMAND), even if I `sudo ps`. Must be one of those securely obfuscated "security features". Gawd, they must have worked really really hard in Cupertino to make this OS even more unusable than Windows...

Answer (score 21):

The following adds on to Mateusz's answer, pretty printing the variables one per line:

```
ps eww -o command <PID>  | tr ' ' '\n'
```

Comment: It's helpful and makes for a better answer if you explain what each component does.

Comment: If you're curious, [explainshell](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=ps+eww+-o+command+1234++%7C+tr+%27+%27+%27%5Cn%27) can break this down.

Comment: This doesn't work if environment variable values have spaces in them

Comment: @LesHazlewood: It does "work" for environment variables with spaces in them, it's just completely useless because it is impossible to disambiguate.

Answer (score 1):

I have created [the envps utility for this](https://github.com/henrik242/envps), based on Samuel's [xproc](https://github.com/time-killer-games/xproc/) code:

```
$ envps 607
LaunchInstanceID=5345193B
XPC_SERVICE_NAME=no.example.ExampleExtension
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

You can build it yourself or install it using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/):

```
brew install henrik242/brew/envps
```

Answer (score 0):

See the function [environ_from_proc_id()](https://github.com/time-killer-games/xproc/blob/main/process.cpp#L1243):

```
  std::vector<std::string> environ_from_proc_id(NGS_PROCID proc_id)
```

From the specified PROCID, (typedef for `DWORD` / `unsigned long` on Windows, otherwise `pid_t` / `int` for Mac, Linux, and other Unix-likes), the function shall copy a vector of environment strings (NAME=VALUE) to 'buffer', and the amount of strings shall be copied to 'size'. This function is not thread safe, however the source may be modified so that it can become thread safe. Note that this uses an incompletely-documented structure on Windows, and in order for it to be able to read the environment block between (to and from) both 32-bit and 64-bit processes, it uses a method that is not as performant as the other platforms. It is built with secondary executables compiled directly into the initial one, which gets extracted to the Windows temp directory at runtime, and runs from there. Depending on the architecture of the target process's associated executable image, that will determine the architecture of the secondary executable to run.  Wrote for Windows, Mac, Linux, and FreeBSD. Ubuntu / Debian needs `libprocps-dev`, also `libx11-dev` if compiled using the `build*w.sh` build scripts which include windowing code, (not the default). FreeBSD will need `libX11` if built with windowing.

Or, compile from the source code using the build scripts (MinGW / g++ on Windows / Linux, clang on Mac / FreeBSD), then run from the command line passing the `--env-from-pid pid` command line parameters. Pass the --help parameter for the list of all possible options.

For convenience, example usage is in `example.cpp` (the actual CLI code): https://github.com/time-killer-games/xproc/blob/main/example/example.cpp#L80

Comment: Link no longer works.

Comment: @DanielWiddis thanks for the notification, I just fixed it.

Comment: Excellent. Useful link, confirms information I've seen elsewhere but is more easily digested.  I'd suggest you update your answer to highlight the key steps the code does (Call `NtQueryInformationProcess`, then `ReadProcessMemory` from the PEB, then the ProcessParameters and finally the Environment.

Comment: @DanielWiddis this is technically the Apple stack-exchange, so I didn't want to go too far off topic with other platform solutions, but perhaps if I get another person giving me the OK, perhaps a staff member, I'll gladly add more details for the Windows-specific approach. I've already given a lot of off-topic info otherwise I'd do it now.