# How can I inspect the environment variables of a running process in Big Sur?

Tags: terminal, bash

How can I see env vars of a running process? The solution from [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/140327/how-can-i-inspect-the-environment-variables-of-a-running-process) doesn't seem to work:

```
➜  ~ TEST=test /bin/bash -c 'sleep 1000 && echo $TEST' &
[1] 27677
➜  ~ ps eww 27677
  PID   TT  STAT      TIME COMMAND
27677 s010  SN     0:00.01 /bin/bash -c sleep 1000 && echo $TEST
```

I'm looking for value `test`. This is Big Sur 11.6.5 BTW.

Comment: Can reproduce. However, if you execute the ps command with the pid of the sleep process, the environment does show up.

Comment: @glennjackman, in my case it doesn't show anything for sleep either

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that on current macOS for processes in general. The process needs the `get-task-allow` entitlement in order for you to be able to read its environment variables. The hardened `bash` on modern macOS does not have this entitlement.

For programs you make yourself, you can just add the entitlement. For others, you will have to manually add it and `codesign` the binary again. Luckily someone has already made a [small utility script](https://gist.github.com/talaviram/1f21e141a137744c89e81b58f73e23c3) that automates that process.